# Python Typing: Subtype Literal

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

In Python, I would like to "narrow-down", or "sub-type" a `Literal`: I would like to have two `Literal` type aliases, `Parent` and `Child`, and I would like to assure typing-wise, that `Child` is a subtype of `Parent`, i.e. that the arguments of `Child` form a subset of the arguments of `Parent`:

```py
Parent = Literal['a', 'b']
Daughter = Literal['a']   # Should be OK
Son = Literal['b']        # Should be OK
NotAChild = Literal['c']  # Should not be OK, because 'c' is not in Parent.__args__
```

**Is it possible to express this relation between the children and the parent type, so that the typecheckers will throw an error on `NotAChild`?** (If yes, how?)

Subclassing a `Literal` type is not allowed. The following code throws a `TypeError: Cannot subclass typing.Literal['a', 'b']`

```
class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to quote [Jelle Zijlstra's answer from the typing-sig mailing list](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/typing-sig@python.org/thread/F3AFA5KH67ZF4ONEW5MN7VDWOEQEHUYX/):

> You can do this as with any other subtyping relationship, by creating a dummy function and passing your object to it.

With the definitions of the question, this results in:

```
def demands_parent(p: Parent) -> None:
    pass

def check(x: NotAChild) -> None:
    demands_parent(x)  # type checker error
```

This is probably not ideal, as it requires writing the dummy functions - it would be preferable if the relation between the Parent and the Child classes would be defined directly when defining the types. But this solutions does not require any runtime-checks, and relies only on the typecheckers.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably impossible with static type checkers. You can enforce it on runtime, if applicable, with [`typing.get_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args):

```
from typing import Literal, get_args

Parent = Literal['a', 'b']
Daughter = Literal['a']
Son = Literal['b']
NotAChild = Literal['c']

assert set(get_args(Daughter)) <= set(get_args(Parent))  # OK
assert set(get_args(Son)) <= set(get_args(Parent))  # OK
assert set(get_args(NotAChild)) <= set(get_args(Parent))  # AssertionError
```

It is far from excellent (even if you refactor to extract function like `assert_literal_child`), because this approach mixes type checking and runtime. However, you can put this into separate test file and say that both this test and `mypy` are complementary parts of your test suite.